Solving SLE in non square matrix using inverse matrix method
I have a system of linear equation consisting of 5 equations with 4 unknown variables $w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4$. I need to check if the SLE has a unique solution and what the solution is. I know that if the number of unknowns are equal the number of equations, I can express the SLE in form, $Ax = b$, and calculate the determinant of $A$. However if the number of unknowns is one less than the number of equations, what happens if I pad $A$ with additional column $(0,0,0,0,1)$ to make it a square matrix? If we express $x$ in form ${[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5]}$, and calculate $x = A^{-1}b$, why do I get the correct result for the 4 unknowns, $w_1 = x_1, w_2 = x_2, w_3 = x_3, w_4 = x_4$?

Why not choose four equations, solve that system and from the set of solutions find the subset of functions that also satisfies the fifth equation?
